# How to get the median of a Binned Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Suppose that i have a data frame below:

```py
df[['Age']]
    Age
1   22-24
2   40-44
3   55-59
4   40-44
5   22-24
```

How do i get a column with the median age just as below.

```py
df[['MedianAge']]
    MedianAge
1   23
2   42.5
3   56.5
4   42.5
5   23
```

Comment: Why is 41.5 the median of 40-44?

Comment: Post edited. I computed it manually. Thanks. Do you have a solution to the pandas-question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def f(x):
   ages = x.split('-')
   return (float(ages[1]) + float(ages[0])) / 2
df['MedianAge'] = df['Age'].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Comment: Thanks. The lambda and split works. I just have to tweak the function to correct the median. (range/2) is not equal to the median, but thanks i can figure this out.